# Cant read JSON file imported from MongoDB using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, mongodb, bson

I am trying to read a json file into a pandas dataframe, the import from MongoDB from completed as below

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
        db = client.airport_database
        c = db.clean_airports_outputs
        #this next line was to remove the extra line '_id'
        cursor =c.find({}, {'_id': False})
        docs = list(cursor)
        json_data = json_util.dumps(docs, indent = 4)
        with open('clean_airports_outputs.json', 'w') as file: 
            file.write(json_data)
        messagebox.showinfo("File Imported", "\n'clean_airports_outputs.json' imported")
```

when I try to read this file with pandas, I get

```
"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"
```

My original json file before I imported to MongoDB was this,

[image: How I want the JSON file to look]

however the exported json file I am writing becomes this,

[image]

I want to write the file as per the first picture without the outer array wrapper square brackets, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

my apologies all, I have worked it out

```
docs = list(cursor)
docs = docs[0] #this line will remove my square brackets 
json_data = json_util.dumps(docs, indent = 4)
```